# take the value from path in location and return it along with a string in nginx

Tags: nginx, path

I am a newbie in the world of Nginx. While learning it, I am trying to accomplish this: I want to return a string whenever someone hits this URL: /greet/user and the string will be 'Hello user.' So, if someone hits localhost/greet/john, the page will show this string: 'Hello john'; if the URL is localhost/greet/merry, the string will be 'Hello merry.'

I tried doing that with the following code fragment. To note, I did use a regular expression to catch any argument that came second.

```
location ~/greet/(user+) {
    set $user user;
    return 200 'Hello ${user}';
}
```

What am I missing here? And how should it be done?
My OS is Ubuntu 22.04. This is my first post on server fault, and I am new to the world of web servers. So, if I miss out on anything while writing this post, I hope I will not receive any penalty.

Comment: That "regular expression" is nonsense. You are capturing the character sequence `use` followed by one or more `r`.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, then how should it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. What I did wrong was in the regular expression. It was capturing any number of 'r's followed by use.

So the correct code was the following:

```
location ~ /greet/(\w+) {
    set $user $1;
    return 200 'Hello ${user}';
}
```

I set the first word to a variable named user and returned it with a string.